Error when connecting from NodeJS to MySQL using Docker and containers - ECONNREFUSED
I'm using Docker Compose to define two services: one for the NodeJS App and the other for MySQL.
This is the docker-compose:
services:
  app-node:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      mysql2:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql2
      DB_USER: lucasfer
      DB_PASSWORD: contra31
      DB_NAME: test-docker
      DB_PORT: "3308"

  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports: 
    - "3308:3308"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: contra31
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test-docker
      MYSQL_USER: lucasfer
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: contra31

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

This is the Docker file that's used to containerize nodejs app:
FROM node:18-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./dist/index.js"]

The NodeJS app is the following:
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import mysql from 'mysql'
import { createUserTable, insertInitialUsers } from './src/DatabaseService.js'; 

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT)
});

const app = express()
const PORT = 3000;

createUserTable(pool)
insertInitialUsers(pool)


app.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err: any, results: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Database error' })
        }
        res.json(results)
    })
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor NodeJS corriendo en puerto ${PORT}`)
})

Database service file:
import { Pool } from "mysql";
export function createUserTable (pool: Pool) {
    pool.query(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            firstName VARCHAR(255),
            lastName  VARCHAR(255),
            email     VARCHAR(255)      
        )
    ` , (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
        console.log('Tabla users creada exitosamente')
    })
}

export function insertInitialUsers (pool: Pool) {
    return pool.query(`
        INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, email)
        VALUES  ('Lucas', 'Ferrero', 'lucasdavidferrero@gmail.com'),
                ('Juan', 'Perez', 'juanperez@gmail.com'),
                ('Pedro', 'PicaPiedra', 'pedrito@gmail.com')
    `, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
        console.log('usuarios insertados correctamente')
    })
}

When I run docker compose up I get the following error from the nodejs app:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.3:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at file:///app/dist/index.js:22:5
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:106:12) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.21.0.3',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}

I've tried to connect to MySQL with a client (Adminer), and It works perfectly fine. I wonder why I get this error from Node.js app.

If you run docker-compose up -d and it fails once, does it work the second time?  If the mysql2 container exists (the host name resolves, you get an IP address) but the database isn't running yet (you get a "connection refused" error) it's possible the application starts before the database is fully initialized.  Also see Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y.

Does this answer your question? Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y

Added condition: service_healthy in mysql2 depends_on property makes MySQL fully ready before the node app gets started, but, I still get the same error.

@LucasDavidFerrero did you add a healthcheck to the mysql2 service?

@Phil Yes, I did. I've updated this post.

Forget to mention that I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows.

exit 0 is not a valid healthcheck. Why would you not simply follow the advice in the suggested duplicate?

I think the problem is within your environment variables in node code,try to print them and check does everything okay with them as your message says that you are using 3306 port which is default for mysql2 client.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.3:3306


You need to ensure that MySQL is ready to accept connections. There are a variety of ways to do this.
One option would be to have your Node code retry connecting to MySQL.
Alternatively you could implement a health check in your Docker Compose file:
services:
  app-node:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql2
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql2
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    depends_on:
      mysql2:
        condition: service_healthy

  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-pcontra31"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120

Here, to avoid replication, I have moved the credentials across to a .env file:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=contra31
MYSQL_DATABASE=test-docker
MYSQL_USER=lucasfer
MYSQL_PASSWORD=contra31

For testing purposes I updated your index.ts to test the connection by executing a simple query.
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import mysql from 'mysql'

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT)
});

const app = express()
const PORT = 3000;


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("user:     "+process.env.DB_USER);
    console.log("password: "+process.env.DB_PASSWORD);

    pool.query('SELECT 1', (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
        }
        console.log('Database connection successfully created.');
    });
})

Build and run:
docker-compose build && docker-compose up



Tried this but I keep getting the same error. Seems that is not related with the MySQL init process, since I'm trying to connect with it after the initial process run successfully.

You tried the setup in my answer and got the same error?  That's rather surprising.

I see that you have added a health check to the database service in your question but I think that your check (exit 0) is not really adequate.
